# Ionic cordova - Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

While executing

> ionic cordova build android

command, getting following error.

> (node:17852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource
> busy or locked, open
> 'D:\project\xxxx\xxxx\www\assets\fonts\xxx.woff'
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:17852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)

I did following things, but no luck.

1. ionic clean cache --force
2. Kill java.exe from task manager
3. Delete the corresponding file and again create it.
4. I don't install any antivirus in my system which blocks it.

Can anybody have any idea about this? Actually code was working fine and suddenly facing these problem.

Regards

Comment: Is your system Windows 10? Did you apply its last update some days ago?
I got a similar problem recently, after updating Win 10. Tried a lot of tricks but the problem persists.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69972078/vue-js-with-webpack-how-to-fix-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked?noredirect=1#comment123698875_69972078

Comment: @vess try this below answer, which could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Time being I fixed the problem by deleting all the fonts from ***'D:\project\xxxx\www\assets\fonts'*** from this folder and copy paste the font from ***'D:\project\xxxx\node_modules\ionic-angular\fonts'*** every time.