# Vue.js with webpack: How to fix ERROR EBUSY: resource busy or locked

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, quasar

I have several Vue 2 & 3 and Quasar based projects that have been working like a charm. Suddenly all of them broke. Now each time I alter some code in an app it breaks with an error in the console *for example*:

```
[webpack-dev-server] ERROR in ./src/pages/Main.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):
  Error: resource busy or locked, open 'D:\www\vue\myApp\sr  c\pages\Main.vue'
```

This happens with **every** vue component I try to change. After searching in the web I found a lot about similar errors arising in other frameworks and tried to follow the advises but without success. I created several new default apps but they behave in the same way. Did I break some piece of code in my PC elsewhere? How can I restore normal operation?
Please, help.

Comment: Maybe your IDE is trying to be too smart and perform version control on your files - so it locks them? You can try https://unlocker.en.uptodown.com/windows to see which process is locking your files.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - Thanks, I don't use any IDE in this case, just good old Notepad++

Comment: This is a misleading error message. Look through the entire output for the real cause of this error. It could be wrong version of nodejs or incompatible version of npm dependencies.

Comment: @kots - This is the only emitted message into the console (presumably by node module *rimraf* on some I/O operation). No clue about what causes the error.

Comment: That's why I offered you to try the Unlocker tool - but you can also use a similar tool from Nirsoft (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html)